# Maven build to Fail for checksum difference

Tags: maven-2, repository, artifactory

I am trying to prevent release version override.
One of the options is to check the checksum, and if it is different (which mean - new file under the same name), fail the build.
Is it possible?

Comment: what you want to know exactly ?

Comment: i have uploaded a jar into artifactory with a version 1.0 the same was modified and build using maven without version change. I need to fail the build for that. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compare checksums for that. Just [configure the permissions](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions) to prevent deletions. This will effectively prevent overrides of released artifacts.